# problem with admin url ubuntu server

Tags: magento-2.1

after install lamp ubuntu 20.04 i achieved to install magento 2.1.4 version
i can show home page but i can't reach to admin login page .
as well as using this command to detect the exact url
php bin/magento info:adminuri

Admin URI: /admin
'backend' => [ 'frontend' => 'admin' ]

baseurl/admin didn't work
a2enmod rewrite
i tried all method such as file root .htaccess
change the apache2.conf to    AllowOverride All
change the value in databases in table 'cor_config_data' and column 'web/seo/use_rewrite' to 0
systemctl restart apache2.service [image]
i tried most method which i found but without any result

---

[[image]

Comment: If you are installing a fresh magento then you should install magento 2.3 or 2.4 why you are using so old version

Comment: i have some issue in my work that's why need to run old version then will upgrade

Comment: did you run setup upgrade and compilation

Comment: then remove the var/view_processod and var/cache folders

Comment: regarding remove var/view_processod and var/cashe using this command 
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*

Comment: still not working?

Comment: yes still not working

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cookies or private window , or try to use firfox

Comment: First of all check your admin name in app/etc/env.php , you will find this e.g 'frontName' => 'admin' or search frontName in this file if it is OK with any confusion again verify secure and unsecure urls from cor_config tab, last but not least, sudo php bin/magento cache:flush and give permissions and than again cache:flush and now open url in incognito or private browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions for the folders and files

permission for files
`find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`
permission for directory
`find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
permission for var, pub and etc folder

```
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step and test it's working.

First of the set the permission Magento files than run below all command.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml sudo rm -rf var/cache sudo rm -rf var/composer_home sudo rm -rf var/generation sudo rm -rf var/page_cache sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed sudo rm -rf var/log sudo rm -rf generated/code/ sudo rm -rf generated/metadata/

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```